# How to take binary data file from an aes decryption and save as tar.gz archive

Tags: go, encryption, openssl, aes, binaryfiles

I started with the encrypted archive (foo.tar.gz.enc). I used Golang to decrypt the file successfully using aes-cbc-128, but the resulting data is a mess of binary that I decided to dump into foo.tar.gz.bin for now. Using go, how do I go about building the foo.tar.gz.bin file into the foo.tar.gz archive?

The data goes through functionally the same process as the OpenSSL call:

```
openssl enc -aes-128-cbc -d -iv xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -K xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -in Foo.tar.gz.enc -out Foo.tar.gz
```

...but without the ability to build the archive. If I save my resulting data to file (foo.tar.gz), it is unrecognizable as an archive.

This is the last chunk of my code that leaves me with the binary data:

```
key := hex.EncodeToString(decryptedKey)

f, err := ioutil.ReadFile(encryptedFilePath)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error reading encrypted tar.gz: %s", err)
}

cBlock, err := aes.NewCipher(key)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("New AES cipher error: %s", err)
}

if len(f) < aes.BlockSize {
    log.Fatalf("cipher too short")
}

f = f[aes.BlockSize:]

if len(f)%aes.BlockSize != 0 {
    log.Fatalf("cipher is not a multiple of the block size")
}

mode := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(cBlock, iv)
mode.CryptBlocks(f, f)
```

I'd greatly appreciate it if anyone could shine a little light on the process. It's my last step in what has been a wonderful three-day-long decryption adventure.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

What Topaco points out in the comments below is absolutely correct. The IV is supplied to me. The line `f = f[aes.BlockSize]:` does not belong here and needs to be removed. I made some changes and handle RW a little differently. The code below results in a recognizable .tar.gz archive, albeit one that is 20 bytes smaller than the successfully decrypted archive, that throws a "truncated gzip data" error (not surprising when we're missing those 20 bytes).
Ignoring errors only in copy/paste for brevity.

```
f, err := os.Open(encryptedFilepath)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatalf("Error reading encrypted tar.gz: %s", err)
}
defer f.Close()

cBlock, _ := aes.NewCipher([]byte(hexStrDecryptedData))

cbc := cipher.NewCBCDecrypter(cBlock, hexIV)

target := filepath.Join(sp.GetDirectory(), "Foo.tar.gz")
fout, _ := os.Create(target)

stats, _ := f.Stat()

var encBlock = make([]byte, 16)
var ReadProg int64 = 16
m := make([]byte, 16)

for ReadProg != stats.Size() {
    if _, err := f.Read(encBlock); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ReadProg += 16
    mode.CryptBlocks(m, encBlock)

    if ReadProg == stats.Size() {
        pad := m[15]
        m = m[:16-pad]
    }
    fout.Write(m)
}
```

EDIT 2:

Figured out that the whole issue was incorrect handling of the padding. Now that I've corrected it, all lights are a go. I will post the solution in the morning - time for sleep. Thanks for the help, Polk and Topaco.

Comment: *...If I save my resulting data to file (foo.tar.gz), it is unrecognizable as an archive...* Then your decryption method is almost certainly not working. Why do you think it is? What is going on with this line: `f = f[aes.BlockSize:]`?

Comment: I'm not sure. Simply because it passed, which is foolish. So I can expect the SUCCESSFULLY decrypted binary to be written to tar.gz without any extra processing? If so, I know where to look.

Comment: It's been a long time since I played with go. What is going on with this line: `f = f[aes.BlockSize:]`?

Comment: It's a bit of code I borrowed when I had several failures. I don't understand it, yet, either. I've been trying to read a bit deeper into it.

Comment: `iv := f[:aes.BlockSize]` and `f = f[aes.BlockSize:]` would separate IV and ciphertext, assuming they were actually concatenated during encryption. The OpenSSL statement does not use concatenation. Instead, the IV is explicitly specified. If the Go code is _functionally_ identical, the ciphertext should consist of all the data from `f` and the line `f = f[aes.BlockSize:]` probably needs to be removed.

Comment: Was about to note the same. I have the IV supplied to me. After removing that line, and handling the RW process a little differently, I've made it to the point of getting an archive file out of the ordeal, though it's 20 bytes smaller than the successful archive generation and throws an error "truncated gzip data". So close, yet so far... Will update above